# Is it possible to parameterize ClaimsProvider & TechnicalProfile at runtime in a custom B2C policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to parameterize ClaimsProvider & TechnicalProfile at runtime in a custom B2C policy?

For example, is it possible to make string substitutions or use variables/claims for XML value like the Metadata Item?

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Demo-OIDC">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://{parameter}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
      </Metadata>

... shortened for example
```

I want to use something similar to Claims Resolvers but within other XML elements.

Comment: Not that I know of :\ Looks like you want to configure a specific AAD tenant via a query string parameter?

Comment: Claims resolvers work only in input and output claims I think

Comment: @juunas I just need to build the Metadata url string dynamically